# Trying to start external program (.hta) file in PHP

Tags: php, exec

For a school project, I've written a webapp to take a picture (using a camera) and do some analysis on it.  There is a tool I downloaded called DIYPhotoBits (capture.hta) which remotely fires the camera shutter, and I am trying to start it with php.  The problem is, NONE of the below commands work.  The server just hangs like it's waiting.  Error logs reveal nothing.  If I enter the path that is below into Windows Explorer, the program runs just fine.

Does anyone know why?  Thank you so much.

```
popen('C:/Users/Nick/Documents/Webpages/microplate/executables/capture.hta', 'r');
exec('C:/Users/Nick/Documents/Webpages/microplate/executables/capture.hta');
system('C:/Users/Nick/Documents/Webpages/microplate/executables/capture.hta');
passthru('C:/Users/Nick/Documents/Webpages/microplate/executables/capture.hta');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `shell_exec()` function or the backtick operators (``)

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for being a batch newbie, but have you tried starting the program by prefixing the 'start' command before the path? I've been trying to start an executable file with the command you've given to PHP, unsuccessfully.

Also is your .hta extension assigned a program to open it with..?